# Can i use vi command (eg.5DD) in bash programming?

Tags: bash

it's me again. I am encountering another problem
First i need to match a certain pattern ,For example:

```
dfsdf
sdfd
sdfs
sdf
vcv
ssdff
sdfdsf
adssa
```

i need to match sdf , then i need to delete the following lines of a fixed number (eg.3DD)
can i  use the vi command in bash programming? Or are there any way to acheive it ?thanks again

Comment: It is better when your questions can be understood alone, without expecting the audience to remember another question you asked. This question leaves open, if you want to match the lines in a file, from user input, etc, and what you exactly mean by 'delete'.

Comment: Thanks. One more question , can i copy the file in different folder by using the bash programming . eg. c:/folders/test  If i want to copy things in folders, is it necessary to put the bash program in folders file?

Comment: it's not neccessary, you can use absolute paths (for example: 'c:/somewhere/over/the/rainbow') instead of relative ones ('over/the/rainbow', which implies your current working directory has to be c:/somewhere)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Again, `sed` comes to the rescue! To work on the lines following a match:

```
sed "/^sdf$/,+3 d" file
```

This will remove the matching line, and the three following it. Just change the 3 to any number of lines you want to remove. Also, note that this will happen for every occurence of "sdf" in the input.

Just realized I might have misread the question. If you do not want to remove the matching line ("sdf" in this case), you can do like this:

```
sed "/^sdf$/,+3 {/^sdf$/b skip; d; :skip}" file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it manually then, open this text file with,

```
less -N x.txt
```

grep for string "sdf" using `/sdf`. You will see your keyword highlighted. Keep pressing n, to get to the next occurring of the string. When you want to switch to `vi`; just press `v`. To revert to `less`, just do a save and exit (`ZZ` or `:wq`).

Comment: Which editor is opened depends on the environment variables `$VISUAL` and `$EDITOR`. If nither is set, it will open `vi`.

Answer (score 0):

Bash is not an editor, it is a shell. It supports `vi` keys for command-line editing, but it does not really supports editing whole files. (Of course, you could program an editor in bash (using `read`, loops, patterns and `echo`), but bash is not the right tool for this.)

To programatically edit files, try `sed`.